# Change Theme Scheme in 5.0.2?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How would I go about changing the theme scheme of PhpMyAdmin in 5.0.2?

I've tried changing the following in \themes\metro\scss_variables.scss from

```
    // Theme color scheme
    // Values: "teal", "redmond", "blueeyes", "mono", "win"
    // Default: "win"
    // Set this value for the desired color scheme
    $color-scheme: win !default;
```

to `$color-scheme: redmond !default;`

but upon full web server restart, it still doesn't show the new theme.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
yarn run  css-compile
```

in the phpmyadminfolder

Comment: This worked for me. I did have to install yarn, node, sass, and run `npm install` first.